# Receive data from mySQL via php

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please explain why I am getting no result from my below script: 
 When I run the query in phpmyadmin it returns the correct result (the `id`), but running my below php script it echo´s out `"No row found!";`

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['word'])) {
  $word = $_SESSION['word']."<br>";
    echo $word;
    $query = ("SELECT id FROM customer WHERE mobil = $word");
    if (!$query) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else {  
            $results = mysql_query($query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            echo '<pre>', print_r($row), '<pre>';
        }
            if (!$row) {
                echo "No row found!";
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: your query is not valid use $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM customer WHERE mobil = '".$word."'");

Comment: what data type  this mobil fields holds ?

Comment: Use single quotes around the $word variable. I would suggest using PDO rather than the mysql_* functions.

Comment: you can also use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_*

Comment: @CodingAnt `echo gettype($word);` returns a string.

Comment: no no, of ccourse it is a string, but in query, all string set as value must be surround by quote

Comment: I'm longing for the day when an RDBMS vendor dares take the step that non parameterized queries are syntax errors... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE and SOLVED
My above script works fine, thanks to @CodingAnt (who asked: what data type this mobil fields holds?) - I checked my database and it turns out mobil was set to VARCHAR instead of INT. Changed it to INT and now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is invalid, it should be like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY");
```

**Also, you shouldn't use Mysql_ since this is deprecated and soon will be removed.**
Use PDO or MySQLI instead. You can find more info here:

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $results = mysqli_query($query);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($results)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo '<pre>', print_r($row), '<pre>';
    }
     else{
            echo "No row found!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = ('SELECT id FROM `customer` WHERE mobil = "$word" ');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
<?php
require_once("db_connect.php");
  if(isset($_SESSION['word'])) {
     $word = $_SESSION['word']."<br>"; //Getting word here       
     $query = "SELECT id FROM customer WHERE mobil = $word";
     $result = mysqli_query($db,$query); //$db holds the database connection
     if (!$result) 
       {
         die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($db));
      }
     else
    {
     $result_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); //Getting the no. of rows
     if($result_rows!=0)                      // If any record present,the below code executes
     {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
       {
            echo '<pre>', print_r($row), '<pre>';
        }
     }
     else
     {
       echo "No rows found";                 // If no record found,this prints.
     }
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Database connection (db_connect.php) :

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
```

***Note*** : **Mysql** is depreciated. You should use either **Mysqli** or **PDO**.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.

Change this:

```
$query = ("SELECT id FROM customer WHERE mobil = $word");
```

To:

```
$query = ("SELECT id FROM customer WHERE mobil = '".$word."'");
```

But your code has many security issues.